# OData client for .Netframework 2.0

Tags: .net-2.0, odata

Is there a client that I can consume OData service in a .Netframework 2 application? Haven't found a clear answer / example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is (haven't seen it yet). You can download the 3.5 client from codeplex here http://odata.codeplex.com/ and try to port it to 2.0. But then again, why can't you use the 3.5 directly (since it's the same CLR as 2.0, just more libraries).

Comment: The client is running on Windows 2000 Server. Believe .Net 3.5 is not supported for Windows 2000, but .Net 2.0 is.